# Preview the text contents from HtmlEditor control(ajax) on A4 size paper and save it as .txt

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am doing asp.net project using C#.I want to display the contents that are being typed in HtmlEditor control onto a A4 size as preview and i also want to save this content to a file(.doc or .txt).

How do i do it??

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Set page size

There is no way with JavaScript, HTML, CSS currently to set the page size for printing. It is in the CSS spec, but there is very limited support for it.

### Save file

There is no IO in JavaScript. The best bet is to send the content to the server and return headers that force a downoad of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind html editor content in variable and then display variable in client side.

server side:

```
Private static string abc=string.empty;

abc=htmlcontrolname.content;
 databind();
```

on client side:

```
<%= abc%>
```